# Two pages with same content

Tags: wordpress

How to create two pages with same content?
For example, the first page should be with a header menu and the second page should be without a header menu.
The page of my theme has an options `without header`
Or I can use two different templates of page, but the content of pages should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

Create a file, called `page-mytemplate.php` under your theme directory.

In that file, start with this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

Create a page, and set the template to `My Custom Page`.

At here you can do whatever you want.

For the other page, repeat the steps, but just call the other template something different name.

**EDIT**

When you want to show the same content with different templates, just simple get the content of the page:

```
$post = get_post($postId);
echo $post->post_title ."<br />";
echo $post->post_content;
```

You can wrap this with your two template page. See the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post)

Comment: I know how to create template for the page.
I asked how to create two pages with the same content, but with different page templates